# How can i create multiple triggers for one camera?

Tags: remote, canon-600d, wireless-triggers

I am trying to find away to link up my canon 600d with multiple remote triggers, preferably wireless. My overall aim is to have all these triggers linked together so that they all have to be pressed in order for the camera to take a photo.

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'd need to have three triggers under their own system which in turn triggers the camera.  I'm assuming you want it all wireless and in which case you can definitely roll your own with an Arduino or something of that ilk, but building custom triggers is probably quite a way out of scope for photo.SO.  Good luck though

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the reason you need this kind of triggering mechanism? Is it part of a game of some kind?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest poor man's way would simply be to take a simple trigger that works off a circuit closing.  Remove the switch, wire up a bunch of additional switches in series and the circuit won't be completed unless all switches are pressed.  It requires some manual work, but is probably the absolute cheapest way you could accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 3):

I use the Camera Axe (http://www.cameraaxe.com) with great success. Its an open source project that's been around for a while and has a fairly large user and support base.

The device has four phono plugs which can each be configured as an input or output trigger. Simply connecting a wireless device (e.g. PocketWizard) to these ports will let you trigger a camera or just about anything else like a flash.

If you want to save a bit of money and build your own Camera Axe, as I've done, you will need to know how to deal with electronics soldering. A fully assembled version is currently priced at $185 (USD) whereas the build-it-yourself kit is only $85 (USD). Note, the kit does require the additional purchase of an Arduino (http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) microcontroller board at around $30 (USD).

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a budget but here goes. You can have Pocket Wizards (Plus, Minis or Flex(es)) on each camera with sync cable from the PW to the camera. On triggering the master camera, it should set of the cameras.

There's a link [here](http://www.pocketwizard.com/products/cable_accessory/cameracables/) that describes it more in detail.

**Pros**

- Easy to use
- Pretty much a no brainer if you already have a set of this around
- Readily available (but do note there may be 3rd party alternatives)
- It's not a DIY so it looks prim and proper.
- Decent to very good range of the units. Not sure if you can get this with DYI.

**Cons**

- It's expensive even for the cheaper Plus X (a recent model)
- You'll need batteries (well depending on how many you are setting up)
- You'll need cables.

Comment: This is the opposite of what he is asking for.  He is asking how to have multiple switches required to set off one camera, not how to do a remote shoot sync.

Comment: It's also worth noting that what you are suggesting can be done more cheaply and directly with the built in remote sync shooting and a bunch of speedlite transmitters.  They can do it right through the hotshoe.

Comment: @AJHenderson - You can trigger of one camera with multiple PW's. Yes I am fully aware that they are expensive, can you add your reply as an answer for the question?

Comment: but can you have the camera only go off when all the PWs are triggered at the same time?  That's what the question is asking for.